# how to fix. [Deprecation] getCurrentPosition() and watchPosition() no longer work on insecure origins.

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-chrome, maps

I got one console error when i try to run the code in my temp server "[Deprecation] getCurrentPosition() and watchPosition() no longer work on insecure origins. To use this feature, you should consider switching your application to a secure origin, such as HTTPS".

in my header am linking the script tag.

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBlS6vRUDeM0XdliZ4iWDyDMekH45wYcck&libraries=places" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Get your current position: 
        Click here

```
    <p id="demo"></p>

    <script>
    var x = document.getElementById("demo");

    function getLocation() {
      document.getElementById("start").value = "";
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
        } else { 
            x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
        }
    }

    function showPosition(position) {
        x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
        "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
        document.getElementById('cityLat').value = position.coords.latitude;
        document.getElementById('cityLng').value = position.coords.longitude;
    }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
var directionDisplay;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var map;

function initialize() {
  directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
  var bangalore = new google.maps.LatLng(12.9716, 77.5946);
  var myOptions = {
    zoom:12,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    center: bangalore
  }

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
}

function calcRoute() {
  var startLat = document.getElementById('cityLat').value;
  var startLong = document.getElementById('cityLng').value;

  var endLat = $('select.end').find(':selected').data('lat');
  var endLong = $('select.end').find(':selected').data('long');

  /*alert(startLat+"---"+startLong+"---"+endLat+"---"+endLong);*/

  if(startLat && startLong){
    var start = new google.maps.LatLng(startLat, startLong);
  }else{
    var start = document.getElementById("start").value;
  }

  var end = new google.maps.LatLng(endLat, endLong);

  var distanceInput = document.getElementById("distance");

  var request = {
    origin:start, 
    destination:end,
    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
  };

  directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      distanceInput.value = response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value / 1000;
    }
  });
}
</script>
```

when i run the above code snippet in my local system i getting the map correctly.

when i move the code to testing server am getting the console error "[Deprecation] getCurrentPosition() and watchPosition() no longer work on insecure origins. To use this feature, you should consider switching your application to a secure origin, such as HTTPS"

I tried without https the script tag source link.

Anybody could you please give me a suggestion for this ?
Thank you.

Comment: That is not problem with scripts you include, but with your domain. You have to host your web on HTTPS protocol, not HTTP. Google don't like HTTP at all.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why Geolocation HTML5 getCurrentPosition() is not working on Google Map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42488129/why-geolocation-html5-getcurrentposition-is-not-working-on-google-map)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Geo Location not working in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37429618/geo-location-not-working-in-chrome)

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript Google Maps API - Center on User's Location not loading map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43623427/javascript-google-maps-api-center-on-users-location-not-loading-map)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Embeded google maps does not show in chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39823554/embeded-google-maps-does-not-show-in-chrome)

Answer (score 1):

You need to install SSL Certificate. There is no quick fix for this solution. Google Chrome and other browsers are blocking this for security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome has disallowed the usage of getCurrentPosition() for websites without SSL.

Google Maps API could solve this but its usage limits is way low.